# Chrome Extension: Run injected script before the application javascript

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am working on a Chrome Extension. This extension has to set a few window variables before the website JS loads. To set these window variables, I am injecting a script from the content-script into the document.

The issue I am facing is that the injected script is running after the website's JS loads.
I need the injected script to run before the website JS so that the values are properly initialized.

**Current Execution Order:**

- Content Script -> Website JS -> Injected JS

**Desired Execution Order:**

- Content Script -> Website JS -> Injected JS

Is there any way that the injected script can be forced to run before the application JS?
I have no control over the Website JS, so the configuration will have to be on the extension.

**manifest.json**

```json
{
  "name": "script-injector",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://localhost:*/*", "*://127.0.0.1:*/*"],
      "js": ["content.js"],
      "run_at": "document_start"
    }
  ],
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "resources": ["injected.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

**content.js**

```js
console.log("CE: Content Script Loaded");

function injectScript() {
  const script = document.createElement("script");
  script.src = chrome.runtime.getURL("injected.js");
  (document.head || document.documentElement).appendChild(script);
}

injectScript();
```

**injected.js**

```js
console.log("CE: Injected Script Loaded");
window.someVar = true;
```

Comment: Both the current and desired execution order are "Content Script -> Website JS -> Injected JS"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run the code in the context of the page (aka `MAIN` world) directly since Chrome 111.

1. Specify `"world": "MAIN"` for your content script
2. Remove web_accessible_resources and injected.js

Your new content.js:

```js
window.someVar = true;
```

Your new manifest.json:

```json
{
  "name": "script-injector",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["*://localhost:*/*", "*://127.0.0.1:*/*"],
    "js": ["content.js"],
    "run_at": "document_start",
    "world": "MAIN"
  }]
}
```

Note that in this MAIN world your script can't access `chrome` API of your extension, so if you need that you'll need a second content script (without specifying `world`) and then use `CustomEvent` messaging, [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19312198).